$G$-crossed (braided) fusion categories and Tannaka duality
Many important concepts in tensor category theory have their counterpart in Hopf algebra theory under Tannaka duality. They have the general form: let $A$ be an XX-algebra, and let Rep$(A)$ denote the category of finite dimensional representations of $A$. Then Rep$(A)$ naturally has the structure of a YY-category. For example, if $A$ is a (quasitriangular) Hopf algebra, then Rep$(A)$ naturally has the structure of a (braided) fusion category, where the coproduct and counit of $A$ defines the monoidal structure of Rep$(A)$ and the universal $R$-matrix of $A$ leads to a braiding in Rep$(A)$. See this page for a list of known Tannaka dualities.
I wonder if $G$-crossed (braided) fusion categories also has a natural counterpart in Hopf algebra theory?
$G$-crossed (braided) fusion categories has found important applications in symmetry-enriched topological phases.
My naive guess is a Hopf algebra $A$ with a $G$-symmetry defined by a group homomorphism $\alpha:G\to\mathrm{Aut}_{\mathrm{Hopf}}(A)$. Then it seems that $G$ has a natural action on Rep($A$). But I don't think this is the complete story, because
the classification of symmetry-enriched topological phases involves group cohomology [up to $\mathcal{H}^4(G,U(1))$], and I can't imagine how to incorporate such structures into my naive guess.
